# How to remove button press in(Pushed in) effect

Tags: html, css

I have a button and when I click on it (when the mouse button is pressed and not released) the button on the page is pushed in(squeezed)(towards the screen) like 3D effect. and when I release the mouse button it becomes normal

what I want to do is to remove this effect but I just can't figure it out..

any help?

Comment: can you post it in JSFiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nsjfym5s/

Comment: @user3456351 `<button>` element is **not a Void Element** and as such needs a closing  `</button>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the :active state. (you also want to do this with the :visited state)

```
a:visited {
    properties
}

a:active {
   properties
}
```